# How to read Headers Parameter on server side "RESTLET"

Tags: netsuite

```
    [I am trying to send parameter with GET request on RESTLET Netsuite !! 
    but i am continuously facing issue 403 forbidden when i am trying to concatenate parameter with URL , without parameter Request is working good and getting response but i want to send parameter so now i am trying to send parameter through Header but not able to read on server side !! please help me out .how to read request header values/parameters on Netsuite RESTLET.  

    1-first i tried concatenate with +"&name=asd" and then Uri builder throws error 403 forbidden
    2-Now i am sending parameters through request.header.add("name":"asd") working good
```

This is my client side request code in which i am attaching parameters in request header

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Headers.Add(header);
    request.Headers.Add("email", "polutry@key-stone.co");
    request.Headers.Add("password", "123-4567");
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();///here i got 403 on concatination ////






  function getCustomer(context)
          {
            var request =https.request.headers;///headers function not defined
             // var email =request.email;
              //var password = request.password;  
          }
```

Want to get header values on server side][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEB68.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RESTlet you don't have access to request-headers, instead you get all the arguments passed to RESTlet in *scriptContext*(function argument to RESTlet entry point, `get` in current case).

Check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4634148062.html) out on how to use RESTlet and how you can pass arguments.

**Note:** Add `{ "Content-Type": "application/json" }` header since you want to pass data to RESTlet.